# Is there a command to copy an entire folder (along with contents) to another location in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
xcopy C:\Users\xp\AA C:\Users\xp\BB /s
```

This copies the content of the directory AA to directory BB but I want to copy the entire folder AA to be copied to BB.

Example: Source has a folder AA which contains files a.txt, b.txt.
The command above copies a.txt,b.txt to the BB folder but I want the folder AA to be copied into BB so that it becomes:
C:\Users\xp\BB\AA\a.txt

Comment: `xcopy /I /S C:\Users\xp\AA C:\Users\xp\BB\AA`?

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of suggestions using COPY, XCOPY, ROBOCOPY and what not but all failed to create the source folder.

Using a small batch file (with absolutely no error checking) does the job for me:

```
for %%D in (%1) do set d=%%~nD
md %2\%d%
copy %1\* %2\%d%
```

Calling this batch file like this `mycpy.cmd C:\Temp\AA C:\Temp\BB` copies the folder *AA* including it's content to *C:\Temp\BB*.

Or in one line:

```
for %%D in (%1) do md %2\%%~nD && copy %1\* %2\%%~nD
```

Answer (score 0):

it's general usage is:

ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]

typical usage: robocopy source destination /E /Z

/E - will make proper dir tree (includes empty dirs)
/Z - restartable mode, specially useful if copy over network

ROBOCOPY C:\Users\xp\ C:\Users\xp\BB\ /E /Z [/XD dirs [dirs]... :: eXclude Directories matching given names/paths.]

Comment: On my Windows 7 (German) this copies all files from **A** to folder **B** without creating a folder **A** inside folder **B**.

Comment: @mrt end destination with \ not just a name, should help

Comment: ROBOCOPY C:\Users\xp\AA C:\Users\xp\BB\ /E /Z should work

Comment: Already tried that, same result: The files are just copied from AA to BB without creating folder AA.

Comment: @mrt ROBOCOPY C:\Users\xp\AA C:\Users\xp\BB\AA  /E /Z seems You will have to repeat dir name for destination; if its var in a script You will have to add it to your dest var.

Comment: Sure this works, but it's not useful if you want to copy multiple folders to another folder, e.g. copy folder AA, BB and CC from folder XX to folder YY.

Comment: @mrt if You need multiple then in source go one level up and if there is something you don't want to copy, you can easy exclude it from list:
ROBOCOPY C:\Users\xp\ C:\Users\xp\BB\ /E /Z [/XD dirs [dirs]... :: eXclude Directories matching given names/paths.]